# How to learn ROS2 properly

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Sorry it is a bit bad topic. My problem is ROS2 is too complicated and hard to track.

there is lots of term and there is no proper description of them.

For example I want to publish lidar data, there is a laserscan msg type, it says some parameters. But there is no example how can i made it correct. how should i publish tf2 data? with same node or different. is there anything that I should do?

How people use ROS2 and do this work?

In short I cant image workflow in ROS2 and I want to understand ROS's logic.

ROS2 is like more complicated video edit program, and i need to learn its language? any advise?

thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393420/how-to-learn-ros2-properly/) by [IM Sezer](https://answers.ros.org/users/92276/im-sezer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

Browse and work through the tutorials in the documentation [there](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/) and [there](https://roboticsbackend.com/category/ros2/), then read A LOT of code.

Try to find examples, demo projects and packages on GitHub that suit your needs, also try to build something yourself too, with simulation and hardware too if you can, e.g. (this base project [dolly](https://github.com/chapulina/dolly)) - with this approach you can see overall picture of the ROS2 and profits of it's modularity. You have to learn by doing there.

Good practices will come over time, now focus on building something that will work :)

You can later try to work with some open-source projects and maybe even help in development.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2021-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1